# Django Form wizard - How to save selected items in many to many field

Tags: django, django-models, manytomanyfield, django-formwizard, django-formtools

So I have a form divided in two steps using the Django formtools Form wizard. The form is working, the data is being saved, except for the manytomanyfield items.

Users can create an Ad which can be filtered by tags. The Tag model is related to the Ad model through a manytomanyfield, however on saving the form, the selected tags are not saved within the Ad model.

## models.py

```
class Ad(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = RichTextField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag')

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

## views.py

```
FORMS = [
    ('title', AdCreateFormStepOne),
    ('tags', AdCreateFormStepTwo),
]

TEMPLATES = {
    'title': 'grid/ad_form_title.html',
    'tags': 'grid/ad_form_tags.html',
}

class AdWizardView(SessionWizardView):
    form_list = FORMS

    def get_template_names(self):
        return [TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        instance = Ad()
        for form in form_list:
            instance = construct_instance(form, instance, form._meta.fields, form._meta.exclude)
        instance.save()
        # After the instance is saved we need to set the tags 
        instance.tags.set(form.cleaned_data['tags'])

        return redirect('index')
```

So I guess I still have to handle the manytomany relation in the done method for the AdWizardView. I saw the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21152731/django-manytomany-field-using-through-and-formwizard) answered but the solution throws an error...

> 'odict_values' object does not support indexing

Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

With best regards,

Edit: Just for clarification, the object in the Tag model already exist, theri selected using a CheckboxSelectMultiple() widget on forms.

Answer (score 0):

Alright! got it!

When saving an instance with a many to many relation you can't save this field directly, apparently you need to set the fields after you save the instance.

## views.py

```
def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
    form_data = [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list]
    instance = Ad()
        for form in form_list:
        instance = construct_instance(form, instance, form._meta.fields, form._meta.exclude)
    instance.save()
    # Select the tags from the form data and set the related tags after the instance is saved 
    instance.tags.set(form_data[1]['tags'])

    return redirect('index')
```